# How to create a sandbox environment in Clio Manage?

Tags: clio-api

We need to perform tests in Clio Manage, including for the integration with QBO.
We can create a QBO sandbox, but I cannot find how to create a Clio sandbox... any idea? How do you test your custom API integrations without messing up the live data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a trial account with Clio and apply for it to be converted to a developer account through this [form](https://www.clio.com/partnerships/developers/developer-intake/). For that account, you can also populate it with sample data [provided by Clio](https://docs.developers.clio.com/handbook/build-your-app/populating-your-account-with-sample-data/).

Full details and instructions can be found on [Clio's Developer Hub](https://docs.developers.clio.com/handbook/getting-started/get-a-developer-account/)

Comment: That's what support tells me too... and no backup&restore feature available, only manual export then import via CSV files. I was hoping for something easier/faster.

Comment: @flo5783 You could take advantage of the relaxed rate limits for non-peak hours for exporting / importing data through the API... It may not be faster, but depending on your situation, it could be a lot easier.